# Implement an AngularJS front-end to a Spring back-end

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot back-end and need to implement an AngularJS(2) front-end to consume my REST API (both running on a single server). I'm a beginner but I haven't found a decent tutorial/demo to help me get started, considering that the following image is my project structure.

[image]

Comment: I don't know anyone can really help you.. this question is like "how can i make a spa using angular2 and spring" and it does not have a single answer...

Comment: No it's about configuration, really.

Comment: there is no specific configuration required to get angular 2 with spring. all you need to do is make sure that your spring server deals with rest, and I suggest keeping both spring and angular2 as two separate projects hosted in same machine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to have a look at jhipster (https://jhipster.github.io/), it's a yeoman generator that gives you a very nice, clean and tested codebase mixing a spring api and an angular front end. You can set up a project pretty fast and learn a lot from it's structure.

Answer (score 0):

You should place the front-end in `resources/public` or `resources/static` or the third one which I don't remember.

Possible directory structure can be:

[image]

in `resources/public`.

You also should point to that folder in your `pom.xml`.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```